# fetch data from database and display in dropdownlist

Tags: php, html

I am trying to fetch a data from my database and display it in my dropdownlist
but i cant get the result I try the other post here but  cant understand

anyone can help me with this this is for my project

```
<?php

    $connection =mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '','mjj_app');

    $sql="SELECT food FROM menu";
    $lists=mysql_query($sql);

    echo"<select name='fname' id='mySelect' value='Foodname'>"

    while($food = mysql_fetch_array($lists)) {
       echo '<option value='.$food['food'].'>'.$food['food'].'</option>'; 
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated, it only makes sense they wouldn't work together. Do not use `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` togather

Comment: @Suyog already change it but still got an error

Comment: @Suyog syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: you are missing semi colon at the end of `echo"<select name='fname' id='mySelect' value='Foodname'>"`

Comment: @Suyog got no error now but got no result :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually using the `mysql_` database extension you also need to select a database using `mysql_select_db()`

You also need to check that each call the the `mysql_` extension has not returned any errors.

```
<?php

    $connection =mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '','mjj_app');
    if ( ! $connection ) {
        echo 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    if ( ! mysql_select_db('DATABASE_NAME') ) {
        echo 'Cant select database : ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    $sql="SELECT food FROM menu";
    $lists=mysql_query($sql);
    if ( ! $lists ) {
        echo 'Query failed: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    echo"<select name='fname' id='mySelect' value='Foodname'>"

    while($food = mysql_fetch_array($lists)) {
       echo '<option value='.$food['food'].'>'.$food['food'].'</option>'; 
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

> As you are obviously still learning, spend your time learning the `mysqli_` or `PDO` database extension. The `mysql_` extension has been deprecated for years and will totally disapprear in PHP7, out sometime soon, which will make you code obsolete. See [this post its a good read and will help you decide which suits you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: hey @RiggsFolly can i ask another thing plsss

Answer (score 1):

You were missing database selecting step, using `mysql_select_db`

Also it is good practice to catch the possible errors or zero number of records returning from query. Please see below code.

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if(!$connection) 
    {
        echo 'Could not connect to server because : '.mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if(!mysql_select_db('database_name')) 
    {
        echo 'Could not select database because : '.mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT food FROM menu";
    $lists = mysql_query($sql);

    if($lists)
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($lists) > 0)
        {
            echo "<select name='fname' id='mySelect' value='Foodname'>";
            while($food = mysql_fetch_array($lists)) 
            {
                echo '<option value='.$food['food'].'>'.$food['food'].'</option>'; 
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No records found.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error while fetching records : ".mysql_error();
    }
```